# Sequelize, how do I get current value of updating row?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

How do I get the current value of the row I'm about to update?
Do I have to do a findOne query before I do an update, in order to find the previous value?
Here's what I want to do:
`UPDATE userModels SET nonce = nonce + 1 WHERE u_id = 1`

Is there some way to make that work from here? How would I get [CURRENT VALUE OF NONCE]? Do I have to do a separate query?

```
return userModels.update({
        nonce: [CURRENT VALUE OF NONCE] + 1
    },{
        where: {
            u_id: 1
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#incrementing-certain-values-of-an-instance

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, it works for me :

```
 return userModels.update(
     { nonce: sequelize.literal('nonce + 1') },
     { where: { u_id: 1} }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

As docs say, the updated value of an object should be retrieved again.
@LJ_1102 commented [this link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#incrementing-certain-values-of-an-instance)
but here [on the API implementation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#incrementfields-options-promisethis) you can see a better explanation.

Refer to [reload](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#reload) if you cant to reload an instance and prevent creating it again